# Problema para convertir JSON en objeto JAVA

Tags: java, json, gson

Tengo el siguiente `JSON`, es una respuesta de un `API`:

```
    {  
   "ES1800496542831234567890":{ "transactions":[  
         {  
            "idmovimiento":"714597",
            "fechaoperacion":"2016-05-27",
            "fechavalor":"2016-05-27",
            "descripcion":"descripcion 2",
            "importe":"-1431.43",
            "saldo":"0.00",
            "orden":"2",
            "oficinaorigen":"0901",
            "conceptocomun":"03",
            "conceptopropio":"227",
            "documento":"0000000000",
            "referencia1":"B50574300000",
            "referencia2":"2222222222222222",
            "newreferencia1":"",
            "newreferencia2":"",
            "facturas":"0",
            "documentos":"0",
            "additional":[  
               {  
                  "numcomplementario":"1",
                  "concepto1":"COR1Schindler Espana S.A. ",
                  "concepto2":" "
               },
               {  
                  "numcomplementario":"2",
                  "concepto1":"ES17501A50001726 000",
                  "concepto2":"000007275 "
               },
               {  
                  "numcomplementario":"3",
                  "concepto1":"OTHR Mas detalles de su factura en ",
                  "concepto2":"www.schindler.es FACTURA 3472855286 N"
               },
               {  
                  "numcomplementario":"4",
                  "concepto1":"IF-CIF ESE50110303 RECIBO 48317499\/2",
                  "concepto2":"314048 VTO 28-05-16 "
               },
               {  
                  "numcomplementario":"5",
                  "concepto1":"190000483174992016 0002314048 5 ",
                  "concepto2":" 20150415false "
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "idmovimiento":"714596",
            "fechaoperacion":"2016-05-27",
            "fechavalor":"2016-05-27",
            "descripcion":"descripcion editada",
            "importe":"-1431.43",
            "saldo":"1.00",
            "orden":"1",
            "oficinaorigen":"0901",
            "conceptocomun":"03",
            "conceptopropio":"227",
            "documento":"0000000000",
            "referencia1":"B50574300000",
            "referencia2":"E50110303 ",
            "newreferencia1":"111111111111",
            "newreferencia2":"222222222222222",
            "facturas":"1",
            "documentos":"0"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

He creado las siguientes Clases `JAVA`:

```
    public class Respuesta {

    private String error;
    private List<Cuenta> cuentas;

    public List<Cuenta> getCuentas() {
        return cuentas;
    }

    public void setCuentas(List<Cuenta> cuentas) {
        this.cuentas = cuentas;
    }

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}

    public class Cuenta {

    private String iban;
    private Transactions transactions;

    public String getIban() {
        return iban;
    }

    public void setIban(String iban) {
        this.iban = iban;
    }

    public Transactions getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }

    public void setTransactions(Transactions transactions) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }
}

    public class Transactions {

    private List<Movimientos> movimientos;

    public List<Movimientos> getMovimientos() {
        return movimientos;
    }

    public void setMovimientos(List<Movimientos> movimientos) {
        this.movimientos = movimientos;
    }
}

    public class Movimientos {

    private Long idmovimiento;
    private Date fechaoperacion;
    private Date fechavalor;
    private String descripcion;
    private BigDecimal importe;
    private BigDecimal saldo;
    private Integer orden;
    private String oficinaorigen;
    private String conceptocomun;
    private String conceptoPropio;
    private String documento;
    private String referencia1;
    private String referencia2;
    private String newreferencia1;
    private String newreferencia2;
    private int facturas;
    private int documentos;
    private List<Additional> additional;

    public String getConceptoPropio() {
        return conceptoPropio;
    }

    public void setConceptoPropio(String conceptoPropio) {
        this.conceptoPropio = conceptoPropio;
    }

    public Long getIdmovimiento() {
        return idmovimiento;
    }

    public void setIdmovimiento(Long idmovimiento) {
        this.idmovimiento = idmovimiento;
    }

    public Date getFechaoperacion() {
        return fechaoperacion;
    }

    public void setFechaoperacion(Date fechaoperacion) {
        this.fechaoperacion = fechaoperacion;
    }

    public Date getFechavalor() {
        return fechavalor;
    }

    public void setFechavalor(Date fechavalor) {
        this.fechavalor = fechavalor;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public BigDecimal getImporte() {
        return importe;
    }

    public void setImporte(BigDecimal importe) {
        this.importe = importe;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public void setSaldo(BigDecimal saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    public Integer getOrden() {
        return orden;
    }

    public void setOrden(Integer orden) {
        this.orden = orden;
    }

    public String getOficinaorigen() {
        return oficinaorigen;
    }

    public void setOficinaorigen(String oficinaorigen) {
        this.oficinaorigen = oficinaorigen;
    }

    public String getConceptocomun() {
        return conceptocomun;
    }

    public void setConceptocomun(String conceptocomun) {
        this.conceptocomun = conceptocomun;
    }

    public String getDocumento() {
        return documento;
    }

    public void setDocumento(String documento) {
        this.documento = documento;
    }

    public String getReferencia1() {
        return referencia1;
    }

    public void setReferencia1(String referencia1) {
        this.referencia1 = referencia1;
    }

    public String getReferencia2() {
        return referencia2;
    }

    public void setReferencia2(String referencia2) {
        this.referencia2 = referencia2;
    }

    public String getNewreferencia1() {
        return newreferencia1;
    }

    public void setNewreferencia1(String newreferencia1) {
        this.newreferencia1 = newreferencia1;
    }

    public String getNewreferencia2() {
        return newreferencia2;
    }

    public void setNewreferencia2(String newreferencia2) {
        this.newreferencia2 = newreferencia2;
    }

    public int getFacturas() {
        return facturas;
    }

    public void setFacturas(int facturas) {
        this.facturas = facturas;
    }

    public int getDocumentos() {
        return documentos;
    }

    public void setDocumentos(int documentos) {
        this.documentos = documentos;
    }

    public List<Additional> getAdditional() {
        return additional;
    }

    public void setAdditional(List<Additional> additional) {
        this.additional = additional;
    }
}

    public class Additional {

    private String numComplementario;
    private String concepto1;
    private String concepto2;

    public String getNumComplementario() {
        return numComplementario;
    }

    public void setNumComplementario(String numComplementario) {
        this.numComplementario = numComplementario;
    }

    public String getConcepto1() {
        return concepto1;
    }

    public void setConcepto1(String concepto1) {
        this.concepto1 = concepto1;
    }

    public String getConcepto2() {
        return concepto2;
    }

    public void setConcepto2(String concepto2) {
        this.concepto2 = concepto2;
    }
}
```

Pero cuando intento convertir el JSON al objeto `JAVA` los atributos están vacíos.
¿No es correcta la estructura `JAVA` que he montado? ¿Cual sería la correcta?

Comment: puedes mostrar el código de cómo haces la conversión?

Comment: En ningún momento veo que hagas la conversión de JSON a Java. Por favor, como ha dicho @sakulino adjunta también el código en el que haces la conversión.

Comment: El codigo para realizar la conversión es este
    "AgrFinanciero mvtos = gson.fromJson(jsonMovimientos, AgrFinanciero.class);"

Comment: Por la estructura del Json, debes tener un objeto que se llame "ES1800496542831234567890", y éste debe ser una lista de "transactions". El objeto "transactions" debe tener varias propiedades como "idmovimiento", "fechaoperacion" etcétera, además de tener una lista de objetos "aditional" y este objeto debe tener 3 propiedades "numerocomplementario", "concepto1" y "concepto2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tenés es que para que gson haga su "Magia" todas las variables tienen que tener su nombre bien definido.

tu problema es que el numero de cuenta que vos queres extraer, viene el el Json como si fuera el nombre de un Campo.

yo lo solucionaria de la siguiente manera:

Primero agregar estas dependencias:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.json</groupId>
       <artifactId>json</artifactId>
       <version> LATEST</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
       <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
       <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

las clases que creaste las dejaria igual (Solo que la clase "Respuesta" no la usé).

Y a la hora de convertir el Json hacer esto:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.google.gson.Gson;



    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    Set<String> st = obj.keySet();
    Cuenta cuenta = new Cuenta();
    cuenta.setIban(st.toArray()[0].toString());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Movimientos[] movs = gson.fromJson(obj.getJSONObject(st.toArray()[0].toString()).getJSONArray("transactions").toString(),Movimientos[].class);
    Transactions transactions = new Transactions();
    transactions.setMovimientos(new ArrayList<Movimientos>(Arrays.asList(movs)));
    cuenta.setTransactions(transactions);
    System.out.println(cuenta.toString());
```

jsonData es un String con todo la respuesta.

Con esto creas UNA cuenta con el IBAN y las Transacciones.

espero que te sirva! saludos.-

Comment: Pues al final lo he solucionado como has indicado. Lo único que he tenido que modificar el código que has puesto porque si la cuenta no tiene movimientos el valor para la cuenta es otro array con un json. De todas formas no me parece correcta la respuesta del API.

Answer (score 1):

El código para realizar la conversión es este:

```
AgrFinanciero mvtos = gson.fromJson(jsonMovimientos, AgrFinanciero.class);
```

La variable jsonMovimientos contiene la respuesta de obtenida en la llamada.

Answer (score 0):

El código:

```
AgrFinanciero mvtos = gson.fromJson(jsonMovimientos, AgrFinanciero.class);
```

Es correcto, sin embargo, falta mencionar que debes incluir la referencia de gSon a tu proyecto java. ¿Ya lo has hecho?

Answer (score 0):

Para que GSON sepa convertir el JSON en un objeto debe conocer qué correspondencia hay entre los valores y los atributos de los objetos.

Normalmente el nombre del campo se lo facilita, es decir con

```
{"nombre":"Jhon Wayne"}
```

GSON (o Jackson) saben hacer

```
setNombre("Jhon Wayne")
```

los atributos normales como valores, los arrays como listas, etc. lo harán automáticamente si el nombre de la propiedad en tu bean se corresponde con el que tiene el JSON

*Pero oh cielos*

El JSON que te pasan tiene un atributo 
 ES1800496542831234567890
que seguro que es variable (lo correcto sería que lo hubieran definido como "id":"ES1800496542831234567890" y luego
"data": { ....el resto ....}

ergo, te va a tocar currarte un serializador a mano ya que GSON eso no va a saber convertirlo el solo

Puedes probar a usar un mapa "a pelo" en lugar del objeto de negocio, es una lata pero funcionará

```
Map<String,Object> result = gson.fromJson(jsonMovimientos,HashMap.class);
```

Comment: No me parece correcto agregarle "ES1800496542831234567890" como Id, dado que las circuntancias pueden ser muchas, por ejemplo, si ese Json es la respuesta de un servicio de un proveedor o de terceros, no siempre se tiene la facilidad para modificar los servicios a nuestra conveniencia. En este caso, ES1800496542831234567890 es el nombre del objeto y de está forma se tiene que deserializar.

Comment: Yo no he dicho agregarlo, he dicho que el JSON está mal diseñado, obviamente lo más seguro es que te lo tengas que tragar. Pero si yo hubiera diseñado ese JSON bien: del RFC => "An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  A name is a string.  A single colon comes after each name, separating the name from the value." Se está usando un valor como nombre, desde mi punto de vista

Comment: El diseño tampoco me parece que esté mal, y no es que un valor que se esté usando como nombre, así está definido y como estructura de Json no le veo ningún problema. Si hacemos una analogía a código, el nombre del objeto "ES1800496542831234567890" corresponde a una lista de objetos de tipo "transactions".

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar esta página http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ para crearte tus modelos.

En tu caso sería lo siguiente:

```
public class Additional {

    @SerializedName("numcomplementario")
    @Expose
    public String numcomplementario;
    @SerializedName("concepto1")
    @Expose
    public String concepto1;
    @SerializedName("concepto2")
    @Expose
    public String concepto2;

}

public class ES1800496542831234567890 {

    @SerializedName("transactions")
    @Expose
    public List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();

}

public class Example {

    @SerializedName("ES1800496542831234567890")
    @Expose
    public ES1800496542831234567890 eS1800496542831234567890;

}

public class Transaction {

    @SerializedName("idmovimiento")
    @Expose
    public String idmovimiento;
    @SerializedName("fechaoperacion")
    @Expose
    public String fechaoperacion;
    @SerializedName("fechavalor")
    @Expose
    public String fechavalor;
    @SerializedName("descripcion")
    @Expose
    public String descripcion;
    @SerializedName("importe")
    @Expose
    public String importe;
    @SerializedName("saldo")
    @Expose
    public String saldo;
    @SerializedName("orden")
    @Expose
    public String orden;
    @SerializedName("oficinaorigen")
    @Expose
    public String oficinaorigen;
    @SerializedName("conceptocomun")
    @Expose
    public String conceptocomun;
    @SerializedName("conceptopropio")
    @Expose
    public String conceptopropio;
    @SerializedName("documento")
    @Expose
    public String documento;
    @SerializedName("referencia1")
    @Expose
    public String referencia1;
    @SerializedName("referencia2")
    @Expose
    public String referencia2;
    @SerializedName("newreferencia1")
    @Expose
    public String newreferencia1;
    @SerializedName("newreferencia2")
    @Expose
    public String newreferencia2;
    @SerializedName("facturas")
    @Expose
    public String facturas;
    @SerializedName("documentos")
    @Expose
    public String documentos;
    @SerializedName("additional")
    @Expose
    public List<Additional> additional = new ArrayList<Additional>();

}
```

Comment: brother, bienvenido al sitio! te recomiendo hacer ejemplos basados en la URL que mencionas para darle una mayor calidad a tu respuesta. Saludos!

Comment: @fredyfx gracias, ya he actualizado la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizo Jackson:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Para objetos complejos tendrás que utilizar algo parecido a esto:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Respuesta miRespuesta = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Respuesta() {
});
```

Si así no te funcionase tendrías que deserializar el objeto List de forma independiente:

```
List<Cuenta> miRespuesta = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Cuenta>>() {
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

No se deserializa el objeto porque la estructura está mal definida. Debes tener algo parecido a:

```
public class objetoCompleto {
    public List<transaction> objTransaction;
}

public class additional {
    private String numComplementario;
    private String concepto1;
    private String concepto2;
}

public class transaction {
    private Long idmovimiento;
    private Date fechaoperacion;
    private Date fechavalor;
    private String descripcion;
    private BigDecimal importe;
    private BigDecimal saldo;
    private Integer orden;
    private String oficinaorigen;
    private String conceptocomun;
    private String conceptoPropio;
    private String documento;
    private String referencia1;
    private String referencia2;
    private String newreferencia1;
    private String newreferencia2;
    private int facturas;
    private int documentos;
    private List<Additional> additional;
}
```