# Convertir a objeto Java un JSON (compuesto) devuelto por una API

Tags: java, json, api

El JSON sería el siguiente:

> {"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":300,"main":"Drizzle","description":"light
>   intensity
>   drizzle","icon":"09d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":280.32,"pressure":1012,"humidity":81,"temp_min":279.15,"temp_max":281.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":4.1,"deg":80},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1485789600,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0103,"country":"GB","sunrise":1485762037,"sunset":1485794875},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}

Quiero conseguir algo así:

```
String jsonText = getWeather(symbol.toUpperCase());
Gson gson = new Gson();
Weather weather = gson.fromJson(jsonText, Weather.class);
```

Mi problema es que ese JSON pasaría a ser más de una clase en Java y sólo se hacer la conversión del código con una clase.

Gracias

Comment: Qué quieres decir con "**ese JSON pasaría a ser más de una clase en Java**"? No te entiendo.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente tienes que crear una clase, que en su interior no solo contendrá propiedades de tipos primitivos (string, integers y similares) sino que alguna de sus propiedades será a su vez una clase o coleccion de clases.

Por ejemplo en tu caso seria algo parecido a:

```
class ubicacion{
    coord
    lista weather
    base
    main
    visibility
    ...
}

class coord{
    lon
    lat
}

class weather{
    id
    main
    description
    icon
}

class main{
    temp
    pressure
    humidity
    temp_min
    temp_max
}

...
```

con lo anterior al hacer:

```
ubicacion weather = gson.fromJson(jsonText, ubicacion.class);
```

se te desserializara todo el json en un objeto de la clase ubicacion, que dentro tendrá el resto de objetos.

Disculpa pero no conozco la sintaxis en Java y te lo he puesto todo muy esquematizado. [Esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26866/problema-para-convertir-json-en-objeto-java?rq=1) del sitio te dará una idea de como tienes que hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

ocupa esta pagina para transformar tu objecto json a objecto java

http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/Convert

tu objeto quedaría algo parecido a esto

```
public class Weater
{
    private String dt;

    private Coord coord;

    private String visibility;

    private Weather[] weather;

    private String name;

    private String cod;

    private Main main;

    private Clouds clouds;

    private String id;

    private Sys sys;

    private String base;

    private Wind wind
}

public class Sys
{
    private String country;

    private String sunrise;

    private String sunset;

    private String id;

    private String type;

    private String message;
}


public class Clouds
{
    private String all;
}

public class Wind
{
    private String deg;

    private String speed;
}


public class Main
{
    private String temp;

    private String temp_min;

    private String humidity;

    private String pressure;

    private String temp_max;
}


public class Weather
{
    private String icon;

    private String description;

    private String main;

    private String id;
}



public class Coord
{
    private String lon;

    private String lat;
}
```

una vez que tengas tu objeto, ya puedes convertir tu objeto complejo json a java con la clase Gson.